# Self-hosted development and deployment control panel - does this exist?

Tags: 7, deployment, staging

My company requires a dev/staging/production environment for a new Drupal project. Plus some kind of control panel for managing development workflow and testing, upgrades and backups of code and content.

An obvious choice would be a platform like Acquia Cloud or Pantheon; their control panels do exactly this. But we are unable to use a hosted service; industry regulation means we must host on our own LAMP environment.

I'm familiar with Drush, Features and GIT, but wondered whether there is any distribution, project or commercial package that provides a management backend that pulls these elements together? I guess one of the reasons why Acquia exist is because the answer is no.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you come across [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/)?

Comment: Related to Clive's comment, I'm not terribly fond of working though Aegir's UI. I've been working on a wrapper for its backend, provision, though. https://github.com/letharion/Drupal-build-scripts/tree/drush-ext It's far from "enterprise ready", but might still be useful/interesting to you.

Comment: Thanks! I had vaguely heard the name Aegir but never explored it. Looks great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aegir in and of itself is definitely the route I would recommend.

If you want a complete server + Aegir solution (and are willing to consider a LEMP stack), [Barracuda-Octopus-Aegir (BOA)](https://github.com/omega8cc/nginx-for-drupal) is fantastic (and highly maintained).